# Task sometimes start, sometimes not, why?how to modify it?

Tags: .net, winforms, task

I'm working an an `winForm` project,I added a `listBox` in form，named as `listBox1`.
The code is as follows:

```
private int inputMax;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string[] input = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "end" };
        inputMax = input.Length;
        foreach (string s in input)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(1000, 2001));
            if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(s)));
            }
        }

    });

    Task t2 = Task.Run(() => //t2 sometimes not start
    {
        while (inputMax > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                if ((int)listBox1.Invoke(new Func<int>(() => listBox1.Items.Count)) > 0)
                {
                    listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0)));
                    inputMax--;
                }
            }

        }

    });

}
```

t2,sometimes not start,why? how to modify?thank you!

Operating environment:windows10,.NET4.5.1

There is a problem: when between t1 and t2, plus a MessageBox.Show ("some string"); the program can also work properly, is this why?

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string[] input = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "end" };
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref inputMax, input.Length);
        foreach (string s in input)
        {
            createLog(@"F:\tasklog.txt", "t1---" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "---inputMax:"+inputMax.ToString()+ "\r\n");
            Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(1000, 2001));
            if(listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(s)));
            }
        }

    });

MessageBox.Show("some string"); //Add this,the progaram can work properly,why?

Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while(inputMax>0)
        {
            createLog(@"F:\tasklog.txt", "t2---" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "---inputMax:"+inputMax.ToString()+"\r\n");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if(listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                if ((int)listBox1.Invoke(new Func<int>(() => listBox1.Items.Count)) > 0)
                {
                    listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0)));
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref inputMax);

                }
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scheduling of Tasks is handled by the [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx) and there is **no guarantee** that `t1` will be scheduled for execution **before** `t2`

Since both of the lambdas that you use to define the `Action`s that will run in `t1` and `t2` **close over the same variable** `inputMax` you are probably running into a 
[race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition):

1. `inputMax` is by default == 0 `default(int)`
2. `t2` starts executing first, and `inputMax==0`
3. in `t2` the condition in the while is false and execution stops

Add some logging to see this situation for yourself

It also seems that your program logic is somewhat flawed, because, it looks like `t2` can exhaust the number of items faster then `t1` will be able to produce them (depending of the sleep times you use).

Unless you specifically want to run into a race condition, I think you should use [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) for `t1` and [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) for 't2'

On a final note, even if you use [interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) to set `inputMax` from different threads, in a thread-safe manner - still using **one** counter in a condition is not a good synchronization strategy.

If you still need to coordinate threads via shared state *(not the best way)* - you can calculate a counter before `t1` and `t2` start - and pass the value to both tasks independently, and utilize some form of waiting (sleep/spining), in the spirit of [producer-consumer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern) with blocking consumer part - because `t2` has to know **when to stop waiting for input/messages**.

The other options could be - running the tasks sequentially (using ContinueWith) or using thread signalling technique with one of the [EventWaitHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle(v=vs.110).aspx) subclasses.

Comment: Calculate inputMax before t1 and t2, the program can work properly. Would you please explain why? Through your guidance, I learned a lot and will continue my efforts. thank you very much!

Comment: @Backbone_Moutain - because `t2` somehow needs to know **when to stop expecting new input / messages**. 
Passing a count and using some sleeping / waiting is the simplest way to go about that.

Comment: I understand, please recommend more knowledge about multithreading sites. Thank you

Comment: @Backbone_Moutain, personally I like this free online resource very much, although it is a bit old now http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can think of is that the `inputMax` variable used in both tasks and isn't **thread safe**.

You should use the `Interlocked` class for this to behave correctly. More info on the class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx).

Comment: inputMax = input.Length;--->Interlocked.Exchange(ref inputMax, input.Length);inputMax--;--->Interlocked.Decrement(ref inputMax);